# Automate Charging cycles for always connected devices to wall outlet

Tags: charging, automation

Is there any way to automate charging cycles (like charge only from 40% to 80%) if the device always connected to power outlet? I'm searching for a way to read charging level and send commands to external devices to turn off/on power outlet.

Comment: I recall there were some.

Comment: Apart from what @ibug suggested, there are more in answers there and I use Battery Charging limit that can be configured exactly as you ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Magisk installed, this module [Magic Charging Switch (MCS)](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-magic-charging-switch-cs-v2017-9-t3668427) can automate charging with certain conditions.

I didn't try it but according to the XDA post it's a decent option.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a bit complicated by setting values, but it works.

Comment: @Sathish If you find this answer helpful, would you click the grey tick beside it?